# Activity is lauching so many times from service

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting crazy with this problem, I have an activity linkd with firebase, but, when the Child is removed from database the method "OnChildRemoved" is called 2, 3, 4 times...

```
corridasReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(taxista.getLastCorrida()) && dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Corrida Cancelada");
                if (novaCorrida.getPassageiro().equalsIgnoreCase("Ninguem") && dataSnapshot.child("taxista").getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(taxista.getUserID())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Voce finalizou a corrida!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(dataSnapshot.child("taxista").getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(taxista.getUserID()) && novaCorrida.getKey() == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Você cancelou a corrida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    cancelCorrida();
                } else if(dataSnapshot.child("taxista").getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(taxista.getUserID()) && novaCorrida.getKey() != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "O Passageiro cancelou a corrida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: how did u find out that it is getting called 4 times??

Comment: the command **Log.d("MainActivity", "Corrida Cancelada");** is appearing a lot of times in monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it loops 4 times, it means that it loops over 4 childrens. This means that your `DatabaseReference` is wrong and none of your `if statements` is executed.

You need to go a level deeper and get the childrens of childrens. You can use `getChildren()` method on `dataSnapshot` object.

Hope it helps.